# Автозапуск самописного приложения в mac os x

Tags: c#, macos, автозапуск, xamarin

Добрый день!

С помощью среды разработки Xamarin Studio (бесплатная версия) создал консольное приложение (Файл->Новый->Проект->C#->Консольный проект).
Моё приложение слушает UDP-порт, и при получении пакета, дёргает веб-сервис).

Приложение компилируется и запускается из среды разработки.
Приложение успешно запускается из командной строки:
`mono /Users/myname/Projects/UDPListener/bin/Debug/UDPListener.exe`

Но я никак не могу разобраться, как заставить приложение автоматически запускаться при включении MAC-mini и логине пользователя.

Создал udp.plist, положил его в /Library/LaunchAgents.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>UDPListener</string>
  <key>Program</key>
  <string>/usr/bin/mono</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
     <string>/Users/myname/Projects/UDPListener/bin/Debug/UDPListener.exe</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>
</plist>
```

Далее:

```
#правим права доступа 
chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/udp.plist 
#правим атрибуты 
chmod 755 /Library/LaunchDaemons/udp.plist
```

Перезагружаюсь...

В мануале написано:
Активировать или дезактивировать работающий сценарии можно выполнив команды:

```
#launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/[имя.вашего.файла].plist   
#launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/[имя.вашего.файла].plist
```

Пробовал выполнять эти команды. Перезагружался.
Не запускается моё приложение.

Помогите, пожалуйста.
Как мне запускать моё приложение при логине пользователя?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно создать приложение запускающее shell script:

- Запустите **Automator.app**
- Выберите тип документа **Application**
- Найдите действие **Run shell script** в библиотеке слева или через
  строку поиска
- Перетащите это действие в рабочую область справа
- Вставьте ваш скрипт `mono /Users/myname/Projects/UDPListener/bin/Debug/UDPListener.exe`
- File -> Save

Теперь добавьте это приложение в автозагрузку:

- System Preferences -> Users & Groups
- Выберите пользователя -> Login Items
- Добавьте в список созданный в Automator .app файл

При логине данного пользователя программа запустится.

Comment: Судя по тому, что при логине пользователя и последующей попытке запустить из консоли  
`mono /Users/myname/Projects/UDPListener/bin/Debug/UDPListener.exe`
отображается сообщение, что порт уже открыт, я делаю вывод, что приложение запустилось-таки автоматом. Спасибо!
Вот только я его не вижу. Можно каким-либо образом отображать запущенное консольное приложение?

Comment: Как же так? Тут только что был прекрасный ответ, который мне помог!

Comment: Automator.app -> run AppleScript  
    `on run {input, parameters}  
 tell application "Terminal"  
  activate  
  do script "mono /Users/myname/Projects/UDPListener/bin/Debug/UDPListener.exe"  
 end tell  
 return input  
    end run`.
Сохранить .app файл и добавить в автозагрузку пользователю.  
При логине откроется терманал и запустит программу.

Никак не могу сохранить форматирование кода из-за чего он не работает. Поэтому удалял коммент.

Comment: Это прекрасно! Без лишних заморочек и plist-ов. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй создать папку UDPListener.app и положи свой exe по след пути     `UDPListener.app/Contents/MacOS/UDPListener` (расширение у файла лучше убрать)

в plist пропиши путь до папки UDPListener.app:

```
<array>
     <string>/yourPath/UDPListener.app</string>
</array>
```

Должно помочь

Answer (score 0):

/Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.app.upd.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.my.app.upd</string>
        <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/bin/mono</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/myname/Projects/UDPListener/bin/Debug/UDPListener.exe</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

chmod 644 /Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.app.upd.plist

Answer (score 0):

так точно будет работать:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
        <plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
            <key>Label</key>
            <string>com.my.app.upd</string>
            <key>ProgramArguments</key>
            <array>
                <string>/usr/bin/mono</string>
        <string>/Users/myname/Projects/UDPListener/bin/Debug/UDPListener.exe</string>
            </array>
            <key>RunAtLoad</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        </plist>
```